# Remove <p> tags from tinymce editor on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, tags, tinymce

I'm using the tinymce editor and when i want to remove the `<p>` tags that the editor add by default i'm using `forced_root_block: false` on `tinymce.init`.

It works fine for Firefox and IE but not in Chrome, can someone help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine on Chrome also. Which version of TinyMCE are you using?

BTW a dirty hack to solve this is to open `tiny_mce_src.js` file and look for this

`forced_root_block : 'p',`

and set it to

`forced_root_block : false` or just remove the `p`.